# Permission for PHP on Windows Server

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, plesk

I was trying to use `imagejpeg()` and it's failed. `is_writable()` function returns `false`. So, I assume the issue is with permissions. I have a windows server so `chmod()` won't work. Plesk is installed on the server and I have changed all the permissions to allow but still `is_writable()` is `false`. The server is running Windows Server 2008 R2.

I contacted the hosting company and they recommended this:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772196%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

Would this help...?

Any advice would be appreciated, I have been struggling for days with this issue!

NOTE: I also went changed all the permissions to "allow" under "virtual directory" for the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check "Additional write/modify permissions" in domain's "Hosting Settings":

[image: Additional write/modify permissions]

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately that makes no difference. It still isnt writable.