# how to access directory in plesk (control panel )

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload, plesk

i want to upload file into directory.

When I attempted to upload the following error occurs :

```
Access to the path '/Assest/Images/' is denied.
```

directory permission :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bICsz.jpg)

host setting :

[host setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN8SO.png)

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302475/permission-for-php-on-windows-server

Comment: i checked " Additional write/modify permissions  ", dont worked for me. update question